# Trouble replacing instances of "\\n" with "\n" in python, utf8

Tags: python, text, replace, newline

```
with open('Datasets/[657667769831260191].txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    textdata = f.read()
    ##TODO
    textdata.replace(r'\\n', '\n')
    usermessages = textdata.split(" ")
```

I'm having trouble replacing instances of "\\n" in a text file I've loaded into a JSON database. As part of cleaning the raw text there seem to be plenty of instances of "\n" and "\\n" the former I can deal with, however I cant seem to find a way for it to recognize literal instances of \\n.

Here is an example

```
        "texthistory": {
            "2022-02-02 16:59:10.313359": " Is it ok to pour milk before cereal",
            "2022-02-02 16:59:15.313359": " yes",
            "2022-02-02 16:59:37.313359": " so I can't eat cereal straight from the box\\nlame\\nI hate social norms",
```

as you can see there should be two more chat instances, instead they are left alone.

Comment: The `\n` is escaped when you view it, but not when you read it. If you do `textdata.splitlines()`, you'll find that there are no more newlines or perceived escaped newlines.

Comment: "Here is an example" Is this what you see *when you open the file in a text editor*? Or is it what you see when you display the value of `textdata` from within your program?

Comment: how would I go about escaping this at read? This is the data post replacing, etc. in the JSON

Comment: Please note that strings in Python are immutable. `textdata.replace(r'\\n', '\n')` **does not** change the value of `textdata`; you cannot alter the actual string object, and you can only change the value of `textdata` by assigning something else to it. `textdata.replace(r'\\n', '\n')` creates a **new** string, and then promptly throws it away if you don't do anything else with it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being a combination of multiple comments.

```
with open('Datasets/[657667769831260191].txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    textdata = f.read()
    textdata = textdata.splitlines()
    nl = '\n'
    textdata = nl.join(textdata)
    textdata = textdata.replace('\\n', '\n')
    usermessages = textdata.split(" ")
```